# How to count the number of tags of a specific word in a JSON file using python?

Tags: python, json

I don't understand why I'm having issues finding the quantity of a specific tag in a JSON file. I have the code below where I'm successfully able to print out the list of tags and count how many there are. But how do I successfully make this into a function for a specific word?

Here where i'm able to make the code to output the tags and quantity:

```
hashtags = []
word_list = [] 
for i in range(len(data)):
    if "hashtags" in data[i]["entities"].keys():
        #print( data[i]["entities"]["hashtags"][0])
        hashtags.append(data[i]["entities"]["hashtags"][0])
        #print(hashtags)
        for word in hashtags:
            print(word["tag"])
            word_list.append(word["tag"])
            #print(word_list)
len(word_list)
```

output:

```
...
hydrogen
energytwitter
snjopower
EnergyStorage
energytwitter
EnergyStorage
VESTWOODS
Out[97]: 34191
```

So this makes me think I can easily turn this into a function so below is what I currently have...but I keep getting an output of zero. Since i'm new to python i've noticed that sometimes i put "return count" in the wrong indent but that didn't change anything when i moved that around.

```
def count_tags(word):
    hashtags = []
    word_list = [] 
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if "hashtags" in data[i]["entities"].keys():
            #print( data[i]["entities"]["hashtags"][0])
            hashtags.append(data[i]["entities"]["hashtags"][0])
            #print(hashtags)
            for word in hashtags:
                print(word["tag"])
                word_list.append(word["tag"])
                if word in word_list:
                    count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass `word` as a parameter but later use it as a variable in the `for` loop. This will overwrite the word.

Also, I think your indentation is wrong. The last `if` condition should be 1 level outdented.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention! I realized other code in my file was a bit sloppy that way and after fixing everything noticed that the if condition where it currently is was creating an infinite loop as well - oops! I made the two appropriate changes but still getting an output of zero unfortunately.